# How can I output my results in a triangular format in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a program outputting triangle numbers for a given term (n) and then outputting them in a triangular shape.

My code so far:

```
Dim nth, triang As Integer
Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of terms: ")
nth = Console.ReadLine

For n = 1 To nth
    triang = n * (n + 1) / 2

    Console.Write(triang & vbNewLine)

Next
Console.ReadLine()
```

Basically, instead of this:

```
Console.Write(triang & vbNewLine)
```

I want to output with one less newline per line so I get a format like so:

x

xx

xxx

xxxx

Thanks,

Comment: You don't need to use vbNewLine if you use Console.WriteLine instead of Console.Write.

Comment: Could you explain with another example your problem? ;)

Comment: A triangular number sequence adds the previous terms to get the next so 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 goes to 1, 3, 6, 10. I want this outputted in a triangle format so

1
(enter)
3 6
(enter)
10 x x